# Android In App Billing DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD not coming through

Tags: android, google-play, billing, in-app-billing

I've been playing around the the Dungeons app and also my own billing code and pretty much have everything working except for one strangeness.

It seems that no matter what I do I can't get the DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD to show up in the JSON signed response. If I'm reading thing right, the docs seem to say that I should see the developer_payload in the JSON market response. The Dungeons app seems to think it should see the developer_payload in the json too.

I haven't gotten it to work in my code and it doesn't seem to work in the Dungeons example either on my phone.

Here are some snippets of my code:

```
Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("REQUEST_PURCHASE");
request.putString(C.DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD, "testing 123");
```

C.DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD is:

```
public static final String DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD = "DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD";
```

And here's what I'm seeing in the purchase state changed responses

> 05-14 20:13:08.360: INFO/BillingService(715): purchaseStateChanged got
>   signedData:
>   {"nonce":9005407554096378381,"orders":[{"notificationId":"android.test.purchased","orderId":"transactionId.android.test.purchased","packageName":"com.mypackage","productId":"android.test.purchased","purchaseTime":1305429187752,"purchaseState":0}]}

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I finally figured this out. Turns out that the developer_payload doesn't come through if you're using any of the test android item ids. You have to be using real in app purchase items.

Comment: +1 for providing solution for your own questin.

Comment: Sweet didn't know you could do that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Turns out that the developer_payload doesn't come through if you're using any of the test android item ids. You have to be using real in app purchase items.

Comment: Then how can we test it? Come on Google! Throw us a bone!

Comment: Duh! Android and its documentation live their own live. Thanks, man.