# In-App Billing V3

Tags: android, in-app-billing

i am new in in-app billing google play, and i download example from google and got TrivialDrive project. I just change SKU_GAS into `"android.test.purchased"` but after i success to buy fuel, i got result :

```
02-27 14:24:40.882: D/TrivialDrive(11805): Consumption finished. Purchase: PurchaseInfo(type:inapp):   
{"packageName":"com.example.android.trivialdrivesample","orderId":"transactionId.android.test.purchased","productId":"android.test.purchased","developerPayload":"","purchaseTime":0,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"inapp:com.example.android.trivialdrivesample:android.test.purchased"}, result: IabResult: Successful consume of sku android.test.purchased (response: 0:OK)
```

my question why purchaseTime = 0 ? and what is `developerPayload`? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `purchaseTime=0`, because you are using the android test product : `android.test.purchased`. And about the `developerPayload` here is the api explanation :

```
A developer-specified string that contains supplemental information about an order. You can specify a value for this field when you make a getBuyIntent request.
```

Here you can find more information [Android In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer. another question, if i want just buy once, what have to do in code?because with android.test.purchased i can buy more than one...and i found this http://stackoverflow.com/q/6006517/1468452 , it use android.test.purchased but purchaseTime != 0

Comment: You have `MANAGED` and `UNMANAGED` products. Unmanaged products can be bough multiple times and managed only once. You have to set up this options in your Google Play Developer Account when you are creating your products.

Comment: so if i set MANAGED product, it will just buy once right? and how i can retreive product information that i already bought? example if i change my phone or reinstall my app??

Comment: Take a look at the example in Android SDK, the thing which you have to look closer is this part `IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener` .

Comment: ah.. so IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener it will check my inventory in google right?and i have to do it first before i do something else?

Comment: Yes, it will check the subscriptions if the user owns and all the products. Just take a look at the sdk example and you will understand how it works.

Comment: but if i use android.test.purchased i can't try check inventory, because it dont store in google right?

Comment: yes, you have to create a test app in developer console, create products and work with them.

Comment: with original creditcard?i dont have it, can i set fake cc for testing without android.test.purchased

Comment: you have to set up a test account different from your main account and buy the products with that account to test. after that you can refund all the purchases.